# How can I find the PTUUID of a partition in a Linux IMG file on macOS

Tags: partition, unix

I need to find out the `PTUUID` of a partition on an IMG file. This can be easily done in Linux by using the following command:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid /mnt/hgfs/Downloads/RPi/2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img
/mnt/hgfs/Downloads/RPi/2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img: PTUUID="e8af6eb2" PTTYPE="dos"
```

How can I accomplish the same thing, where the command would print out the `PTUUID` as shown above?

Comment: What is the `PARTUUID` used for? I ask because macOS does not create a `PTUUID` when initializing a drive using the MBR partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will omit the path `/mnt/hgfs/Downloads/RPi/` given in the OP's question.

The `2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img` file can be download by selecting the `Download` link for "Raspberry Pi OS Lite" on the webpage [Operating system images](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/).

The output from the macOS command `file 2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img` is given below.

```
2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xc, start-CHS (0x40,0,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,3,32), startsector 8192, 524288 sectors; partition 2 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x3ff,3,32), end-CHS (0x3ff,3,32), startsector 532480, 3104768 sectors
```

This output identifies the file as being an image of a drive using a MBR partitioning scheme. Therefore, the macOS command given below will print the `PTUUID`. The same command works with Linux.

```
od -A n -X -j 440 -N 4 2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img
```

The output for macOS is shown below.

```
                 e8af6eb2
```

Linux will produce the same values, but the padded spaces may be different. For example, the output for Ubuntu Linux is shown below.

```
 e8af6eb2
```

> Note: This value is ***not*** the `PARTUUID` of a partition on the IMG file given in the OP's question.

The macOS command `fdisk 2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img` does a better job displaying the partition table, as shown below.

```
Disk: 2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img  geometry: 902/64/63 [3637248 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0C   64   0   1 - 1023   3  32 [      8192 -     524288] Win95 FAT32L
 2: 83 1023   3  32 - 1023   3  32 [    532480 -    3104768] Linux files*
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Eventually, the `PARTUUID` of both partitions is just the `PTUUID` with the partition number appended, as shown below.

```
e8af6eb2-01
e8af6eb2-02
```

This can be verified by using Ubuntu Linux. The commands and output is given below.

```
dma@ubuntu:~$ losetup -f # This shows the next available loop.
/dev/loop0
dma@ubuntu:~$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 -P 2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img
dma@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid /dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="DC3E-E470" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="e8af6eb2-01"
dma@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid /dev/loop0p2
/dev/loop0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="a7adb26a-8b87-4729-99c8-9f5ac069d51e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e8af6eb2-02"
```

Comment: Excellent response!  Would you mind where you came across the `440` number?  Is that part of a spec you can reference?

Comment: In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), the `PTUUID` is referred to as the [32-bit disk signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#DISK_ID).